# Remover valores vazio do Request do formulário

Tags: php, array, laravel

Preciso remover os valores que a partir do primeiro input forem vazios.

```
    $count = count($request->item);

    for($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) {

        if ($request->item[$i] === null) {
            unset($request->item[$i]);
            unset($request->descricao[$i]);
            unset($request->quantidade[$i]);
            unset($request->valor_unitario[$i]);
            unset($request->desconto[$i]);
        }

    }
    dd($request->item);
```

esta retornando o seguinte erro:

> "Indirect modification of overloaded property App\Http\Requests\OrcamentosRequest::$item has no effect"

```
    <tr>
        <td><input id="item" name="item[]" type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" value="{{ old('item.0') }}"></td>
        <td><input id="descricao" name="descricao[]" type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" value="{{ old('descricao.0') }}"></td>
        <td><input id="quantidade" name="quantidade[]" type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" value="{{ old('quantidade.0') }}"></td>
        <td><input id="valor_unitario" name="valor_unitario[]" type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" value="{{ old('valor_unitario.0') }}"></td>
        <td><input id="desconto" name="desconto[]" type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" value="{{ old('desconto.0') }}"></td>
        <td><a onclick="RemoveTableRow(this)" id="delete" class="delete"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a></td>
    </tr>
```

Estou recebendo os dados tudo certo, no request, só da problema quando uso o UNSET

Comment: Tem a parte HTML?

Comment: postei.. porém está funcionado.. só da esse erro quando coloco o unset pra remover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que a classe do Request não permite modificação direta na mesma. Uma possível solução é fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
        $count = count($request->item);

    for($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) {

        if ($request->item[$i] != null) {
            $item[]             = $request->item[$i];
            $descricao[]        = $request->descricao[$i];
            $quantidade[]       = $request->quantidade[$i];
            $valor_unitario[]   = $request->valor_unitario[$i];
            $desconto[]         = $request->desconto[$i];
            $orcamento_id       = $orcamento_id;
        }

    }
    dd($item);
```

Comment: testei mano, não funcionou, ocorreu o mesmo erro

Comment: mas request permite modificação sim, porém através do "for" ta dando esse pau no unset

Comment: ou posso ta falando merda também

Comment: eu encontrei um função que é $request->request->remove(valor') porem não sei como especificar de qual chave é.. que se trata do item, mas qual chave é.. pelo caso de ser um array

Comment: Busquei na documentação e vi ela também, tem a função replace, talvez dê pra usar ela com o valor removido, estou codificando um exemplo pra você testar

Comment: show de bola vamos ver

Comment: Analisa essa solução, a ideia é editar o item criando um novo array de itens que não contem o valor nulo atual.

Comment: "Undefined offset: 3"

Comment: você é um gênio mano.. me deu outra ideia.. é só criar outro array, como o nome da própria chave, e depois posso descartar o request.. sacas

Comment: Já estava fazendo isso aqui, ótimo que conseguiu pegar a vibe

Comment: É nois brother tamo junto! vlw